# unknown operator "0" when doing "$elemMatch" in .find()

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

#### Issue

I have a pouchdb-express server I am using for some tests for a CouchDB database.

I have the following database with an item like so:

```
{
    _id: "12345",
    email: 'u0@email.com',
    companies: [{ id: 'company', uid: 'u0' }]
}
```

I then run the following command that works on my API hitting the CouchDB database but does not work when I try it on the PouchDB Express server.

`.find({selector: { "companies": { "$elemMatch": {id: "company", uid: "u0"} } }})`

I get the following error:

> { error: 'bad_request',
>     reason:  'unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type, $allMatch or $all',
>     name: 'bad_request',
>     status: 400,
>     message:  'unknown operator "0" - should be one of $eq, $lte, $lt, $gt, $gte, $exists, $ne, $in, $nin, $size, $mod, $regex, $elemMatch, $type, $allMatch or $all' }

I also get the same exact error during the following query:

```
.find({
  limit:9999999,
  selector:{
    $or: [
      {$and: [{type:"something"},{uid:"u0"}] }, 
      {$and: [{type:"document"}]}
    ]
  }
})
```

I've also tried doing `$eq` almost exactly like the [test suite](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/blob/master/tests/find/test-suite-1/test.or.js) does with still no dice.

Does anyone know why this would happen?

#### Info

- Environment: Node.JS
- Server: PouchDB Server

Here is my package.json

```
"pouchdb-find": "^6.4.3", // tried 7.0.0 and still have the issue
"pouchdb-node": "^6.4.3",
"pouchdb-server": "^4.1.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tinkered with this and discovered that for records like:

```js
{
  "borough": "Brooklyn",
  "cuisine": "American ",
  "marks": [50, 60, 45, 43],
  "grades": [
    {
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 5
    },
    {
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 7
    },
    {
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 12
    },
    {
      "grade": "A",
      "score": 12
    }
  ],
  "name": "Riviera Caterer"
},
```

This simple selector will return the correct results :

```js
{ selector: { '$elemMatch': { '$gte': 0, '$lt': 30 } } }
```

and, while this "composite (?)" selector, **ignores mismatches**, and returns **all** rows!! ...

```js
{ selector: 'grades': { '$elemMatch': { 'score': 14 } } }
```

... this one bombs with the error you indicate :

```js
{ selector: 'grades': { '$elemMatch': { "grade": "B" } } }
```

I suspect the "pouchdb-find" version of `$elemMatch` can only handle simple arrays, not arrays of objects.

Seems like a PR is required :-(